# Spring data Built-in repositories or custom

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, software-design

I need a Generic repository in order to extend and implements specific behaviour if is necessary. For instance, i'll use the half methods of the CrudRepository, but if I extend from this repository I am exposing the other unnecessary methods. Is better use your custom repository instead of use Spring data repositories (CrudRepository, PagingAndSortingRepository)? What about exposing unnecesary methods?

Comment: Why not create an interface type whose underlying implementations leverages the built in Spring repository calls but hides access to the Spring calls you don't want?

Comment: That is the question, Is better practice extends from Spring built-in repositories?

Comment: In general you extend from a class when you want to add additional functionality to it without changing the existing functionality. If you want to shape how a class is accessed then you're changing that class' interface. Which is what the interface type is for.

Comment: It depends on your use case. For Spring Data REST, which does directly expose repository calls externally, "whitelisting" is probably the way to go. For your own internal code--what do you gain by not having the standard complement of methods available?

Comment: @chrylis if i don't gain anything hiding the other methods, Is the best practice use the Spring built-in repositories? why do people frecuently create generic repositories extending from Spring repositories?.

Comment: It's best practice to do the least complicated thing, which is to extend the base repositories. People extend them because you nearly always want to add finder methods (e.g., `Person findByEmailIgnoreCase(String email)`).

Answer (score -1):

`interface MySpringRepoType`

`public class RepoImpl extends SpringRepository implements MySpringRepoType`.

If you access the raw type `RepoImpl` you'll have access to all the SpringRepository ones which you don't want but if you access the interface type `MySpringRepoType` then only the interface defined functions should be visible to the caller. This will allow you to 'hide' any Spring functionality you don't want someone to see.